# Moving a gameObject along a launch arc in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to add a cannon attack that fires bombs in an arc that lands at a target X position.

Here are examples of how the cannon should shoot at targets with different X positions:
[image: Examples of how the cannon should shoot at targets with different X positions]

So far, I only have a script that moves the bomb directly to the player's current X position, without it moving in an arc.

Note: The player's X position is recorded one time before the bomb is fired, so the target position is fixed.

UPDATE: I am trying to find a way to calculate an arc that will have a bomb shoot up, then land at the player's X position at the time that the bomb was fired. So far, I have stored the player's X position in a float called lastPlayerXPos at the time that the bomb was shot, and it goes straight at a Vector2 with the X value of lastPlayerXPos. (Without the curve).

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow up with the same concept of HomingMissiles.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{      

    // increasing velocity, fake acceleration.     
    velocity ++;
    
    // Adding velocity to the rocket
    rocketRigidBody.velocity = transform.forward * velocity ;

    // getting the direction where the Missile should lock toward the target.
    var rocketTargetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rocketTarget.position - transform.position );
    // Rotating the missiles to face the target
    rocketRigidBody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rocketTargetRotation, turnRate)); //turn rate is how fast you want to rocket to look to the target
  
    
}
```

this tutorial also explain in depth what you need to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v_H3oOR0aU

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not trying to make a projectile follow the player. I am trying to find a way to calculate an arc that will have a bomb shoot up, then land at the player's X position at the time that the projectile was shot. I can update the question if this is unclear.